# MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, hibernate

i implemented one to many relationship in hibernate bt i m getting an error for duplicate key , so bit confused as to what to do
if anyone can rectify my mistake it wld be a grt help , its been actually just quite a few days i m into hibernate

this is my college class

```
package com.hibernate.arjun3;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class College {

private String name;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int college_id;
private String location;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getCollege_id() {
    return college_id;
}

public void setCollege_id(int college_id) {
    this.college_id = college_id;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}
```

}

This is my Student class

```
package com.hibernate.arjun3;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;

@Entity
public class Students {

private String firstname;
private String lastname;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int college_id;

@ElementCollection
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="College_Students" , joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="College_Id"))
private Collection<College> college = new ArrayList<College>();

public Collection<College> getCollege() {
    return college;
}

public void setCollege(Collection<College> college) {
    this.college = college;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public int getCollege_id() {
    return college_id;
}

public void setCollege_id(int college_id) {
    this.college_id = college_id;
}
```

}

My Main class

```
package com.hibernate.arjun3;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class Main1 {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    College colg = new College();
    colg.setName("Vivekanand");
    colg.setLocation("Chembur");

    Students students = new Students();
    students.setFirstname("Arjun");
    students.setLastname("Narahari");

    Students students2 = new Students();
    students2.setFirstname("Sagar");
    students2.setLastname("Abhyankar");

    students.getCollege().add(colg);
    students2.getCollege().add(colg);

    SessionFactory factory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    session.save(students);
    session.save(students2);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    factory.close();
}
```

}

**The Error:**

INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: alter table Students_College drop foreign key FK_qk8e1fl454umkjvarmovmdgrp
Hibernate: alter table Students_College drop foreign key FK_n2cycly15ecddgky71345r3u
Hibernate: drop table if exists College
Hibernate: drop table if exists Students
Hibernate: drop table if exists Students_College
Hibernate: create table College (college_id integer not null auto_increment, location varchar(255), name varchar(255), primary key (college_id))
Hibernate: create table Students (college_id integer not null auto_increment, firstname varchar(255), lastname varchar(255), primary key (college_id))
Hibernate: create table Students_College (Students_college_id integer not null, college_college_id integer not null)
Hibernate: alter table Students_College add constraint UK_qk8e1fl454umkjvarmovmdgrp  unique (college_college_id)
Hibernate: alter table Students_College add constraint FK_qk8e1fl454umkjvarmovmdgrp foreign key (college_college_id) references College (college_id)
Hibernate: alter table Students_College add constraint FK_n2cycly15ecddgky71345r3u foreign key (Students_college_id) references Students (college_id)
Sep 27, 2014 12:21:01 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
Hibernate: insert into Students (firstname, lastname) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into College (location, name) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Students (firstname, lastname) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Students_College (Students_college_id, college_college_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Students_College (Students_college_id, college_college_id) values (?, ?)
Sep 27, 2014 12:21:01 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
Sep 27, 2014 12:21:01 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UK_qk8e1fl454umkjvarmovmdgrp'
Sep 27, 2014 12:21:01 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1311)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at com.hibernate.arjun3.Main1.main(Main1.java:31)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UK_qk8e1fl454umkjvarmovmdgrp'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1049)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4208)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2597)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2758)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2826)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2082)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2334)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2262)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2246)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 12 more

hoping for replies from u all experienced ppl
thanking you

Comment: Are you using a sequence table for generating ids? It could be the sequence table still assigns ID 1 although this ID is already taken by an instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping makes no sense.

First of all, I find it a bit strange that a student has many colleges, instead of the reverse: a college has many students. Let's ignore this and see the technical problems:

```
@ElementCollection
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

It can't be an element collection if it's a OneToMany. `@ElementCollection` should be removed.

```
@Entity
public class Students {
```

Why is this entity named `Students`? Every instance represents **one** student. The class should thus be named `Student`.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int college_id;
```

Why is a student identified by a college ID? It should be a student ID. And the field should respect the Java naming conventions. You should rename it `id`.

```
@JoinTable(name="College_Students" , joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="College_Id"))
private Collection<College> college = new ArrayList<College>();
```

Now this is a collection containing several colleges, and you name it `college`, instead of `colleges`. Using the singular form when it should be plural and vice-versa makes your code very confusing.

But the main problem is the following: you said Hibernate that there is a OneToMany association between Student and College. So one college may only belong to one student. Otherwise, it would have to be a ManyToMany. And yet, here's what your code does:

```
students.getCollege().add(colg);
students2.getCollege().add(colg);
```

The same college is added to 2 different students.

Comment: thanku sir for the explanation ,now i get it whr i was wrong , i have one more doubt in which class shld be the annotation one to many or many to one be used , i m asking in general , i get confused in this thought , like if u can give me a small example of actually in which class shld be used , if poss for u